# Is ejabberd suitable for us?

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-api

we want to create a backend for a messenger in our application. We have an iOS&Android client app and a webApplication. We need 1-on-1 chat, group chat, photo/file support etc. All the basic stuff a messenger has.

I also want to see my message archive from all devices: iOS,Android and Web. 
And it should be secure.
Is this all possible?

Last question, what if we have 2 different applications on our server do we need to install ejabberd twice?

I hope somebody can give me some advice.
Thx!!

Answer (score 0):

Ejabberd uses XMPP for doing all tasks that you wants.
ejabberd is just a server setup for your app and it is very suitable for every environment..

You can easily implement things like one to one chat, group chat, photo/video/files sending/receiving even the last seen and user profile management.

There are different ways to archive chats on different plate forms you can use any of these.

There are some library that may help you to achieve you goal.

- Mobile libraries for iOS: XMPPFramework, Jayme

  - REST API Mobile
    libraries for Android: Smack, Retrofit
  - Web library with WebSocket
    support and fallback to BOSH: Strophe

**You can also customise every modules in ejabberd **

So according to me this is the best choice to go for xmpp